# Simpleperf not recording any sample

Tags: android, android-ndk, profiling

I'm trying to profile native code on Android, using the [Simpleperf](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/simpleperf/README.md) tool provided by Google.

I've done every step listed in their example, setting `security.perf_harden` to 0, checking the architecture of the device I'm using (a Nexus 9 tablet), and finally launching Simpleperf with the following command in the device's shell:

```
./simpleperf record -p 10910 --duration 5
```

But as a result, I get

```
simpleperf I 04-05 10:53:27 11773 11773 cmd_record.cpp:341] Samples recorded: 0. Samples lost: 0.
```

And I cannot seem to make Simpleperf record any sample. I have my native library compiled in debug with the `-g` flag, my Android app is marked as `android:debuggable=true` (although apparently I can omit that and just build in debug). At this point I can't put my finger on what might be missing for Simpleperf to record samples.

If I try a simple:

```
./simpleperf report
```

afterwards, this is what I end up with:

```
Cmdline: /data/data/com.my.app_package/simpleperf record -p 10910 --duration 5
Arch: arm64
Event: cpu-cycles (type 0, config 0)
Samples: 0
Event count: 0

Overhead  Command  Pid  Tid  Shared Object  Symbol
```

What am I doing wrong or missing here?

Answer (score -2):

Are you using the app while profiling. If the process has nothing to do on cpu, and is in sleep mode, probably you get no samples.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+show/master/simpleperf/README.md#457